# undefined reference Static Member C++

Tags: c++

I have a code like this. When run, it's return fault: undefined reference to `A::x`. How can I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    static int x;

public:
    A(){
    }

    A(int t) {
        x = t;
    }

    static void f() {
        cout<< A::x;
    }

    int f2() {
        return  x;
    }
};

int main() {
    A::f();
    A a;
    a.f2();
}
```

Comment: Linking code from external hosts is not allowed. Minimal, valid and verifiable sample code, that represents your specific problem, must be included as part of the question.

Comment: you only declared static variable, static variable also should be defined out side of your class.(i.e) int A::x = some_value; your trying to modify static in your code.

Comment: tks everyone, i fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only declared your static variable, not defined it.

Define it outside of the class using:

```
int A::x = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
int A::x = 0; //Or any other value
```

somewhere outside your class declaration.